# Clustering (unsupervised learning) for uneven classes

Tags: clustering, k-means, unsupervised-learning

[image: I have some data set that look like that https://postimg.cc/3y2jx5xR]

I am looking for an unsupervised method that can see also the points that start to look different from the majority. Which clustering techniques (I use python) can be used for such data sets?

I have tried k-means but as I was expecting it has failed considerably to see such peaks.

Comment: Have not tried it myself, but this python package has just released https://github.com/beringresearch/ivis, for both supervised and unsupervised!

Comment: I would not consider that to be a cluster. The values are very much spread out. Maybe you should consider anomaly detection instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with DBSCAN. It's a clustering algorithm that is meant to isolate outliers. You can read more about it [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-dbscan-works-and-why-should-i-use-it-443b4a191c80). It's already available in `sklearn` ([documentation here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html)).

If you tweak its parameters correctly, those "extreme" observations should be identified and separated from actual clusters.